# Fade from background-image to hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, hover, fade

I'd like to fade my first background-image into one that is supposed to be used on hover and then off again once the user removes their mouse. Can use jQuery.

Here is what I have so far:

```
    <ul style="top: -70px; display: block; padding-left: 205px;" id="cats-menu" class="nav superfish sf-js-enabled">
    <a href="http://www.ballpointtech.com/category/guides/"></a><li id="li_guides" onclick="window.location = 'http://www.ballpointtech.com/category/guides/';"><a href="http://www.ballpointtech.com/category/guides/"> </a></li>

    <a href="http://www.ballpointtech.com/category/news/"></a><li id="li_news" onclick="window.location = 'http://www.ballpointtech.com/category/news/';"><a href="http://www.ballpointtech.com/category/news/"> </a></li>
    <a href="http://www.ballpointtech.com/category/reviews/"></a><li id="li_reviews" onclick="window.location = 'http://www.ballpointtech.com/category/reviews/';"><a href="http://www.ballpointtech.com/category/reviews/"> </a></li>
    <a href="http://www.ballpointtech.com/category/tipstricks/"></a><li id="li_tipstricks" onclick="window.location = 'http://www.ballpointtech.com/category/tipstricks/';"><a href="http://www.ballpointtech.com/category/tipstricks/"> </a></li>
</ul>

    <style type="text/css">
    #li_guides {
        background-image:url('http://www.ballpointtech.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/09/Guides-Still1.png');
        width:130px;
        height:92px;    
}
    #li_guides:hover {
        background-image:url('http://www.ballpointtech.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/09/Guides-Rollover1.png');
    }
#li_guides:active {
        background-image:url('http://www.ballpointtech.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/09/Guides-Click2.png');
    }
#li_reviews {
        background-image:url('http://www.ballpointtech.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/09/Reviews-Still.png');
        width:130px;
        height:92px;    
}
    #li_reviews:hover {
        background-image:url('http://www.ballpointtech.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/09/Reviews-Rollover.png');
    }
#li_reviews:active {
        background-image:url('http://www.ballpointtech.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/09/Reviews-Click.png');
    }
#li_news {
        background-image:url('http://www.ballpointtech.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/09/News-Still.png');
        width:130px;
        height:92px;    
}
    #li_news:hover {
        background-image:url('http://www.ballpointtech.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/09/News-Rollover.png');
    }
#li_news:active {
        background-image:url('http://www.ballpointtech.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/09/News-Click.png');
    }
#li_tipstricks {
        background-image:url('http://www.ballpointtech.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/09/tipstricks-still.png');
        width:130px;
        height:92px;    
}
    #li_tipstricks:hover {
        background-image:url('http://www.ballpointtech.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/09/tipstricks-rollover.png');
        }
    #li_tipstricks:active {
        background-image:url('http://www.ballpointtech.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/09/tipstricks-click.png');
    }
</style>
```

Argh, can't get the formatting right...

Comment: Just a thought, but http://jsbin.com is a *wonderful* place... =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here's a good start I put together in jsbin](http://jsbin.com/odoti3/edit). I wired up just the news icon as a demo. It's not bulletproof as leaving the element before the transition completes will leave the element in the wrong state but I don't know how to address that offhand. jquery might have better methods than `fadeOut/fadeIn` for this job. Also you'll want to make the `:active` background `! important` so that image is always visible when clicking, which I forgot to do before saving.

also you can't have `<a>` elements hanging around outside of the `<li>` elements. make links `display:block` so they take up the empty space inside the list item and then you can junk the hacky `onclick="window.location..."`.

Comment: This is a good start :). However, is it possible to fade into each other, rather than fading out and fading in? Also, I'm not finding anyway to do display the active image (onclick basically)

Comment: having cross-fading would require separate images- probably 2 divs and then the empty `<a>` on top of them. each div would have one of the background images assigned to it, and you would call the fade methods at the same time. for the `active` image you could have the image as backround for the `<a>` element which would show over top of the other elements.

Comment: for the active image, would I not have to do something like <a> onclick?

Answer (score 0):

@hunter

this is ignoring the desire to fade.

```
$('your.item').mouseenter(function(){
     $('your.item').stop().animate({opacity: 0},200,function(){

          $('your.item').attr('src','/new/image.jpg');
          $('your.item').stop().animate({opacity: 1},200);
    }
    });




  });
```

this more or less gives the big picture. not tested or proofed. if you give this a shot and put it on jfiddle i will help you through it. you also need to make a `.mouseleave()` function